# Vaadin 12 , Tomcat : Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: gradle, tomcat9, vaadin10

In my Vaadin 12 project the resource bundle files (`*.properties`) are in folder

```
\src\main\resources\
```

In this folder I has files: `labels_es.properties, labels_en.properties`

In my MyForm.kt

```
  val labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels", utf8Control)


    companion object {      
        val utf8Control = UTF8Control()

    }
```

But when deploy war to Tomcat 9 and run my web app I get error:

```
Vaadin 12 ResourceBundle.getBundle Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name labels, locale es
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1299)
        at com.myproject.MyForm.<init>(MyFormt.kt:47)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you try putting your bundles into `myproject\src\main\resources`?

Comment: @Cashbee Not help. Same result

Comment: @Cashbee I updated my post

Comment: and now is work fine.

Comment: haha so what was it? did the `resources` folder help after all?

Comment: @Cashbee Yes, thank you.